# How do I fix for the user inputs to be sent to Firebase database under the User's profile?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

So, say user registration is done (this code is already correct) and the next window asks users to enter personal info (education etc), how do you code that this information goes to Firebase under the user's profile.

I have the registration page done and users created there already go to firebase.

This is what I have for the page after registration. No errors but obviously incomplete.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import CoreFoundation
import AVFoundation
import SwiftKeychainWrapper
import FirebaseDatabase

class FeedVC: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {

navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Sign Out", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(signOut))

        super.viewDidLoad()


        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem

        post()

    }


    //override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
       // super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
   // }


    // MARK: - Table view data source

    //override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        //return 1
   // }

   // override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        //return 5
  // }

    //override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       // return UITableViewCell()
    //}



func post() {


            let MainFunInterest = "MainFunInterest"
            let SomethingInterestingIhaveRead = "SomethingInterestingIhaveRead"
            let JobOrEducation = "JobOrEducation"
            let WhatIamConsideringBuying = "WhatIamConsideringBuying"

            let post : [String : AnyObject] = ["MainFunInterest" : MainFunInterest as AnyObject,
                                               "SomethingInterestingIhaveRead" : SomethingInterestingIhaveRead as AnyObject,
                                               "JobOrEducation" : JobOrEducation as AnyObject,
                                               "WhatIamConsideringBuying" : WhatIamConsideringBuying as AnyObject]

                let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
                databaseRef.child("personal info").childByAutoId().setValue(post)

    }



    @objc func signOut (_sender: AnyObject) {



        KeychainWrapper.standard.removeObject(forKey: "uid")
        do {
            try Auth.auth().signOut()
        } catch let signOutError as NSError {
            print ("Error signing out: %@", signOutError)
        }

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        }

}
```

I can sign out of the page. When I register currently, what goes to firebase is just the stock description that user is expected to enter (for example "education" is registered in firebase rather than what user should type in.

Answer (score 0):

I see you use FirebaseDatabase but I forgot if that's the new FirebaseFirestore or not. Anyway, in this case, you will either need read more firebase database related documentation to create your own database query or you will need to read the data from "education" first then write your own write, update, delete method to handle data changes then repost them or update them.
Hopefully helped!